# How to enable remote debugging with chrome, selenium, chromedriver on mac

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, port

I want to re-use an existing chrome browser that's running on my mac.

From the internet it looks like I need to open chrome with arguments then run the java code and set the port number.  Unfortunately I still get errors.

Open chrome on port 9222 from terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port-9222 --user-data-dir="~ChromeProfile"
```

Java code in program to connect to chrome:

```
    WebDriver dr = null;
    location = "/Users/xx/Downloads/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", location);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
    //options.setExperimentalOption("--remote-debugging-port", "localhost:9222");
    options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222");
    dr = new ChromeDriver(options);
    dr.navigate().to(myLink);
```

Netbeans keeps opening a random port and not 9222;

```
Starting ChromeDriver 9X.X.XXXX.XX (8c61b7e2989f2990d42f859cac71319137787cce-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#306}) on port 4188
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need the sessionID as well as the port.

Comment: Have u tried using `options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");` only and then opening the http://localhost:9222/

Comment: Yes - as you can see its commented out as it was one of the approaches i tested out on my mac. No luck

Comment: I didnt get your point. Why you worry about the changing port. if you can easily use `options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");`  and comment out  `options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222");` and then if u try to open the `http://localhost:9222/` , you will get the chrome inspect screen, where u can debug your application. I hope thats what you want.

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal Is it possible to see the UI as well in the localhost:9222